# Values of sequenced IntegerDigits lists with two fixed elements

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation, digits

How can we access to all values of an `IntegerDigits` list with a special condition. This restriction is the locality of `0` **or** `1` in two special places.

For example if we want to have two `1`s in the first and fourth places of sequenced `IntegerDigits` lists containing six digits, the ordered desired values are `9, 11, 13, 15, 25, 27, 31, 41 ...`. How can we obtain this ordered values?

```
FromDigits[{0,0,1,0,0,1},2]=9;
FromDigits[{0,0,1,0,1,1},2]=11;
FromDigits[{0,0,1,1,0,1},2]=13;
FromDigits[{0,0,1,1,1,1},2]=15;
FromDigits[{0,1,1,0,0,1},2]=25;
FromDigits[{0,1,1,0,1,1},2]=27;
FromDigits[{0,1,1,1,1,1},2]=31;
FromDigits[{1,0,1,0,0,1},2]=41;
and so on
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nbits = 6
ranges = ConstantArray[{0, 1}, nbits]
rangeRestrictions = {-1 -> {1}, -4 -> {1}}
restrictedRanges = ReplacePart[ranges, rangeRestrictions]
FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ Tuples[restrictedRanges]
```

Comment: What is `all` supposed to be?

Comment: @CarlWoll Fixed typo.

Comment: Very interesting and intelligent

Comment: Thank you for reminding. For keeping motivation for more answers, I think we should wait a bit more. However these answers from you, Carl, and kglr are atisfactory.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`Quotient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quotient)/[`Mod`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mod):

```
list[n_] := 16 Quotient[Range[0,n],4] + 2 Mod[Range[0,n],4] + 9
list[15]
```

> {9, 11, 13, 15, 25, 27, 29, 31, 41, 43, 45, 47, 57, 59, 61, 63}

The [`Mod`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mod) operation drops all but the last two binary digits, and then shifts left by 1 binary digit. The [`Quotient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quotient) operation drops the last 2 binary digits, and then shifts left by 4 binary digits. Finally, adding 9 sets the 1st and 4th digits. Verification:

```
Column @ IntegerDigits[list[15], 2, 6] //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  \{0,0,1,0,0,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,1,0,1,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,1,1,0,1\} \\
>  \{0,0,1,1,1,1\} \\
>  \{0,1,1,0,0,1\} \\
>  \{0,1,1,0,1,1\} \\
>  \{0,1,1,1,0,1\} \\
>  \{0,1,1,1,1,1\} \\
>  \{1,0,1,0,0,1\} \\
>  \{1,0,1,0,1,1\} \\
>  \{1,0,1,1,0,1\} \\
>  \{1,0,1,1,1,1\} \\
>  \{1,1,1,0,0,1\} \\
>  \{1,1,1,0,1,1\} \\
>  \{1,1,1,1,0,1\} \\
>  \{1,1,1,1,1,1\} \\
> \end{array}$

**Another answer**

Another possibility is to use bit operations:

```
list2[n_] := BitOr[
    BitShiftLeft[BitAnd[Range[0,n], BitNot[3]], 2] + BitShiftLeft[BitAnd[Range[0,n], 3], 1],
    9
]
```

Check:

```
list[100] == list2[100]
```

> True

**Simple brute force approach for variable columns**

Since you are interested in varying the column indices to fix, another idea is to set all the columns to 1, and then delete duplicates:

```
list3[cols_, n_] := DeleteDuplicates @ BitOr[
    Total[2^(cols-1)],
    Range[0, 2^Length[cols]n]
]
```

For your example in the comments:

```
list3[{1,5}, 20]
```

> {17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 81, 83, 85, \
>   87, 89, 91, 93, 95}

Comment: There is a major problem: Please focus on `{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}` : `8` digits with two `1`s in the first and fifth positions. I used `list[n_] := 64* Quotient[Range[0, n], 4] + 2 Mod[Range[0, n], 4] + 17` but the `list[255]` does not finish to `{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}`!?

Comment: Unfortunately I have to say this does not work correctly.

Comment: `list[n_] := 32*Quotient[Range[0, n], 8] + 2 Mod[Range[0, n], 8] + 17` works for me. What sets of columns are you interested in?

Comment: Instead of `32` I put `64` erroneously!

Answer (score 1):

Using the magic numbers (`2`, `4` `6`)  from @Carl's answer

```
ClearAll[constrainedIntegers]
constrainedIntegers[cols_, n_] := FromDigits[IntegerDigits[Plus@@(2^(cols - 1)), 2], 2] + 
  QuotientRemainder[Range[0, n], 4].{16, 2}
```

Examples:

```
constrainedIntegers[{1, 4}, 15]
```

> {9, 11, 13, 15, 25, 27, 29, 31, 41, 43, 45, 47, 57, 59, 61, 63}

```
constrainedIntegers[{1, 3, 5}, 15]
```

> {21, 23, 25, 27, 37, 39, 41, 43, 53, 55, 57, 59, 69, 71, 73, 75}

```
constrainedIntegers[{3, 9}, 15]
```

> {260, 262, 264, 266, 276, 278, 280, 282, 292, 294, 296, 298, 308, 310, 312, 314}